# Custom options will not up date basket with bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9

I custom option in my bundle product with uses dynamic pricing.

The problem i have having is when i select the custom option it and then press add to cart (i am using one step checkout) the cart price will not add the cost of the custom option price.

I am using magento 1.9.3 and have seem some mention of Product_option needing to be added to catalog.xml but thing didn't seem to work for me.

I have search for a solution and just can see anything that solves this.

Thanks